# Python Youtube API Client Warnings

Tags: python, api, google-api, youtube-data-api

> TLDR, using `google-api-python-client`, it's giving me a couple of warnings,

```
WARNING:googleapiclient.discovery_cache:file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/tmp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 36, in autodetect
    from google.appengine.api import memcache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

> And I want to hide them. How do I hide them?

---

**Details**

I'm using `google-api-python-client==1.6.2` to perform searching using `YouTube data API`. I don't need OAuth in this case, so I've not installed anything besides `google-api-python-client`.

When I run my code, I get a long WARNING with a couple of Tracebacks. My application is still running as I can still use curl to hit the server and I get a result.

```
WARNING:googleapiclient.discovery_cache:file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/tmp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 36, in autodetect
    from google.appengine.api import memcache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/tmp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 33, in <module>
    from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.contrib.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/tmp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 37, in <module>
    from oauth2client.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/tmp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 41, in autodetect
    from . import file_cache
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/tmp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 41, in <module>
    'file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0')
ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0
```

Here's my code,

**`my_package/main.py`**

```
from my_package.server import app

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 8100
app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

**`my_package/server.py`**

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from logging import info
from my_package.youtube import YouTube


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

yt_client = YouTube()


class Search(Resource):
    def get(self, query):
        info("Handling `get` request for the resource 'Search'.")
        return yt_client.search(query)

api.add_resource(Search, '/search/<string:query>')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('Application starting.')
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**`my_package/youtube.py`**

```
from logging import info
import apiclient as google


class YouTube:
    MAX_RESULTS = 25

    def __init__(self):
        info('Creating a YouTube API instance.')
        self.API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY'
        self.youtube = google.discovery.build('youtube', 'v3',
                                              developerKey=self.API_KEY)

    def search(self, query):
        info(f"Performing a search for '{query}'")
        results = self.youtube.search().list(
            q=query,
            part='snippet',
            maxResults=self.MAX_RESULTS
        ).execute()

        return results.get('items', [])
```

Here's my **`requirements.txt`**

```
aniso8601==1.2.1
certifi==2017.4.17
chardet==3.0.3
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.6
google-api-python-client==1.6.2
httplib2==0.10.3
idna==2.5
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
oauth2client==4.1.0
pyasn1==0.2.3
pyasn1-modules==0.0.9
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.17.3
rsa==3.4.2
six==1.10.0
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.21.1
Werkzeug==0.12.2
```

Comment: I've tried using 
`logging.getLogger('google.apiclient.discovery_cache').setLevel(logging.ERROR); 
import apiclient as google`, but doesn't make a difference

Comment: You might try setting the cache_discovery parameter in your build call to False.  google.discovery.build('youtube', 'v3',developerKey=self.API_KEY,cache_discovery=False).  Glancing at the source that looks like it would prevent the attempted import that is logging your warning.  You're not getting any benefit out of that module anyway because it only throws that warning if it can't find an appropriate cache to use.

Comment: @clockwatcher Setting cache_discovery to False did make the warning go away. What do you mean by 'not getting any benefit'. Are you suggesting to not use `discovery.build` to get the youtube api? Is the a better way? I got the api call from the google sample code, but they seem to be using OAuth in there, i'm not.

Comment: @clockwatcher If you want me to accept your answer, you can post it as an actual answer.

Comment: I meant you're not getting a benefit out of the cache portion of the discovery module.  It's warning you that it can't find an appropriate back-end to cache what it finds.  So turning off the cache altogether shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the cache_discovery parameter in your build call to False.

```
google.discovery.build('youtube','v3',developerKey=self.API_KEY,
                       cache_discovery=False)
```

That will prevent the import of the cache.discovery module which is what is logging the warning.